# Selective find in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find, findstr

I want to remove specific pieces of text from a file, though I can only seem to get the whole line of text for `83:                   href="https://website.com/thing.rar"><img`, but when I use when I use `find /V "83:" | find /V "href="` it takes the whole line out.

How could I only selectively choose the link out of the bunch? This is what I've been using so far:

```
findstr /i /n "https://website.*rar" C:\Users\New\output.txt >> C:\Users\New\output2.txt
```

then

```
findstr /i /n /v "83: href= ><img" C:\Users\New\output2.txt >> C:\Users\New\output3.txt
```

Comment: Did you want to get only the url ?

Comment: `findstr` *always* outputs the whole line (or suppresses the whole line with `/v`). `cmd` has no native way for what you want to do. Eiter split the string with a `for /f` loop with proper delims and tokens or use (the help of) another language, which supports proper REGEX.

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/447901 Get a tool that can handle XML such as PowerShell or Python.